# What would be the url in backbonejs Model for updating it ,my rails route is /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.slug = options.slug;

  },
    url: function () {
    var base = '/projects';
    return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.slug + '/tasks';
  }
```

When i tried to save(update) this model task.save({status: completed}) it attempting post request instead of put request and displayed 404 error. and
I need a url to update this model.
my rails route is '/projects/:project_id/tasks/:id'

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the url in a Backbone.Model, you'll need to set the `urlRoot` rather than the `url` property.

Try:

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.slug = options.slug;

  },
  urlRoot: function () {
    var base = '/projects';
    return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.slug + '/tasks';
  }
});
```